# How to insert a line of text into each .obj file in each directory by shell script?

Tags: shell, grep, sh

I need to insert

```
mtllib mesh.mtl
```

line in all of my .obj files. Directory structure is

```
Product1/
   product1.obj
   product1.mtl
Product2/
   product2.obj
   product2.mtl
```

and then I should rename both product*.obj / product*.mtl to mesh.obj / mesh.mtl respectively.

How can I do that by a shell script?

Answer (score 1):

```
for f in Product*/*.obj
do
  echo "mtllib mesh.mtl" >/tmp/$$
  cat $f >> /tmp/$$
  mv /tmp/$$ $f
done

for f in Product*/*.obj
do
  mv $f $(dirname $f)/mesh.obj
done

for f in Product*/*.mtl
do
  mv $f $(dirname $f)/mesh.mtl
done
```

(make a backup before running )

Comment: Thank you. Actually my folder names are not like ordered, it can be everything.And filenames contain whitespaces.

Comment: So you can search with `find` for extension and enclose all var. that points to filenames with double-quotes (like `"$f"`)